# How do I prepare arabic coffee in a stone Dallah?

Tags: equipment, coffee

I purchased a lovely stone [Dallah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallah_%28coffee_pot%29) from Jordan.

[image: A picture of a stone Dallah].

The first and obvious question is: is it safe to prepare coffee in?

However, once that question is answered, the pot certainly *looks* functional. Therefore, using the resources of an Australian household, how do I prepare coffee in one of these strange pots from a different continent?

Answer (score 4):

This is the result of experimentation with Daniele's answer and the resources of a normal Australian household.

**Be prepared with a tea towel or other holding-item. Marble has a huge thermal inertia and insulation is a decadent western invention.**

On the other hand *electric kettles* are awesome.

First: Wash everything thoroughly. I boiled a couple litres of water and poured them through the dallah. I then washed everything with soap and hot water, then rinsed with more boiling water. This told me two things: 1) The marble can handle boiling water. (Which was likely... but good to test), and 2) I wasn't going to be drinking any marble dust.

Then, from a *good* coffee shop that roasts their own beans, get very very very finely ground coffee. Their espresso blend is a good start. While single origin *can* be better, it requires fine-tuning to find the right single-origin for this taste, especially as...

Buy a satchet of cardamom. If you're going to do true Jordanian coffee (instead of Saudi or Turkish) it's a function of which spice you combine. I've heard of cinnamon and saffron also being acceptable, but the "everyday" spice is cardamom. This is where single-origin will get you if you choose a bean that isn't compatible.

Now here is where I cheated. I've got an electric stovetop (boo, hiss... rental apartment. I kind of have to deal with it unless I want to ask a colleague for a bunsen burner.) I also own an electric kettle. I boiled water in the kettle, then measured 250 mils into the dallah, which I placed on a "hob" on my electric stove. I then turned the stove to medium.

After about 5 minutes of watching, the marble was very warm, but the water never boiled. Technically, this is a good thing. I then added 2 heaping 
"standard" scoopfuls (about 20 grams, the scoop that comes with a bodium french press) of coffee mixed with about half a scoop of cardamom. I let that sit on the stove for 4 minutes, stirring the coffee every minute until the crema recombined.

Pour (holding it with a tea-towel) gently into the marble tinytiny cups.

I have to take mine with a few dollops of condensed milk because my *word* this coffee is strong. Good, but strong.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [Making Coffee the Arabic Way, in a Dallah](http://www.arabiancoffees.co.uk/blogs/news/6019986-making-coffee-the-arabic-way-in-a-dallah):

> Before you start making Coffee, you need to decide how strong (or
>   weak) you like it to taste. Below is an indication of how to gauge
>   this when making any of our Coffees:
>
> - 1/2 tablespoon per 250ml cup = Weak Flavoured Coffee
> - 1 heaped
>     tablespoon per 250ml cup = Medium Flavoured Coffee
> - 2 heaped
>     tablespoons per 250ml cup = Strong Flavoured Coffee.
>
> Once you have the quantities sussed, it's on with the making. In using
>   a Dallah with our Coffees, we recommended the following preparation
>   method:
>
> Fill the Dallah with the amount of water you want and place it on a
>   medium heat on a hob Once the water boils remove the Dallah from the
>   flame and allow it to cool for just 30 seconds Next add the desired
>   amount of Coffee to the water in the Dallah and stir well Place the
>   Dallah back on the hob (but on a low heat) for about 2 minutes and,
>   carefully, occasionally stir. Only allow the Coffee to simmer gently.
>   If it threatens to boil just remove the Dallah from the heat (Do not
>   allow it to boil over as this will burn the Coffee) After the 2
>   minutes has passed and the Coffee has reached a simmer, turn off the
>   heat and serve.

Going to your first question, is it safe to prepare coffee in: first of all, if they provide it with small cups, then I bet it can be used to make coffee and drink it.
Trying to be more scientific, at maximum power the kitchen fires reach more or less 1500°C. You should try to understand which kind of stone is your dallah, and then look at its melting point. It should be more than 800°C.

But *in my personal opinion* if you put it on a very low fire (i.e. much less than 1500°C) it will survive (this is only my opinion, I'm not sure!).

Comment: @HichamLEMGHARI Code formatting (`backticks`) is not for emphasis; that's what **bold** and *italics* are for. But the terms you emphasized didn't need emphasis anyway.

Comment: @Jefromi : Got it, Just thought it will be 'more clear' for the reading